# SBS2011 SharePoint 2010 - Word/Excel prompting for password

Tags: sharepoint, windows-sbs, windows-sbs-2011, microsoft-office-2010

I am accessing the built in SharePoint 2010 on SBS2011 via Microsoft Office Excel and Word (opening a file from WebDAV http file mapped drive in Explorer).

When saving a file, I get prompted from within Microsoft Office 2010 Word/Excel for credentials - entering the correct credentials just prompts the window again.

Clicking cancel allows me to go to My computer -> mapped drive and save the file.

I am able to browse the SharePoint site via Internet Explorer without an issue and I am not prompted for a password when doing so, I presume this means Windows authentication is working via the SharePoint URL being in the intranet list.

I have also check that the sharepoint url is in the trusted intranet sites list.

Anything else I should look in to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using the following registry value?  This usually works with integrated authentication (not basic/forms authentication).

```
Key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\WebClient\Parameters  
Value: AuthForwardServerList  
Type: Multi-string
```

Refer to the following document for more information:

**Prompt for Credentials When Accessing FQDN Sites**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943280

Comment: This will work.  We deploy it via GPO here, since our Sharepoint site is a FQDN.  +1

Comment: Hi thanks for link can you please verify kb number as link doesnt work

Comment: @g18c: It is 943280

Answer (score 0):

Here's something to try.

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/choroshin/archive/2012/11/06/sharepoint-getting-authentication-login-prompt-when-trying-to-open-office-document-with-unique-permissions.aspx

> The problem is in opening an Office document which is saved in
>   SharePoint 2010:
>
> 1. When a user has a "read" permission only to a specific document in a
>      document library, but do not have any permissions in the document
>      library level nor the site level.
> 2. When he is accessing the document,
>      he receives the "Download File" message with "Open" / "Save" /
>      "Cancel" options.
> 3. When clicking "Open", he is prompted with a user &
>      password message. When clicking his correct user and password, the
>      user & password message remains – nothing happens.
> 4. Only when clicking
>      "Cancel" in the user & password message, the document opens.
> 5. Users who has read permissions in the document library level or the site 
>      level – manage to open the document successfully, meaning are not 
>      prompted with the user & password message after clicking "Open" 
>      (it opens the document).

There are 3 possible ways to solve this issue:

**1.** Add read only permission in the root of the site collection.

**2.** Deactivate the feature “ViewFormPagesLockDown”:

```
stsadm -o deactivatefeature -url http://SERVERNAME/sites/SITENAME -filename ViewFormPagesLockDown\feature.xml
```

**3.** Run the following script on your site collection, this will add permission level to the “Limited Access” Permission level that you have in that site collection.